# Most pythonic way to check whether all instances of a class have a specific value for a determined attribute

Tags: python, oop, instance

I'm wondering about the pythonic way to know whether all instances of a class have a specific value for a determined attribute.

Let's say we have a class called A and we have created 3 instances from that class called a1, a2 and a3. All these instances have an x attribute.

So what I want to do here is to check whether the instances a1, a2, and a3 have a specific value for the x attribute, let's say -100.

What's the simplest way to do that ?

### NOTES :

1. The x attribute is not constant.
2. The class instances are stored in a list.
3. These instances, each of them has a different x value in the constructor. This value changes during the game but can become constant.

So, here I just wanted to check if all instances have a constant value . And btw when these instances' values are constant, they are all equal to -100, and they don't differ from each other.

Comment: Worry about *a* way to do it first; optimize later. Hint: use `all`.

Comment: @martineau I'm not new to this site and I know most of rules

Comment: @chepner: `all()` or whatever doesn't matter until a reliable way of tracking instances of the class is solved — which is actually the challenging part.

Comment: @martineau I assumed the OP already had references to the instances.

Comment: @chepner: Ah, so the question is lacking important details as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution:

```py
class A:
    instances = []
    def __init__(self):
        A.instances.append(self)
    
    @classmethod
    def all_instances_has(cls, attr, value):
        return all(getattr(ins, attr) == value for ins in cls.instances)

    def __del__(self):
        A.instances.remove(self)

a = A()
b = A()
a.abc = 1
b.abc = 1
print(A.all_instances_has("abc", 1))
```

It will return True, however, as soon as you create a new instance with “abc” equals 2, it will return False:

```py
c = A()
c.abc = 2
print(A.all_instances_has("abc", 1))
```

And now - it’s False.

You can change `getattr(ins, attr)` to `getattr(ins, attr, None)` in order to avoid `AttributeError` in case that a particular instance doesn’t even have this attribute at all.

Comment: A problem with this approach is if you `del c`, it will still print `False` — i.e. it's not really tracking the existence of instances of `A`. There's also a similar issue if an `A` is created as a local variable in a function.

Comment: I would probably use `A.__new__` to update the class attribute `instances`. You can also override `__del__` to remove an instance from the list once the instance really is gone. (`del c` only removes *that* reference to the object.)

Comment: @chepner yes, right. I might override `__del__ `

Comment: @chepner i don't see how overriding `__new__` is better... you create the instance in `__new__` with `object.__new__` which gives you a "self", but you get that self with `__init__` as well, so.. why not

Comment: Semantically, tracking the new object is more closely related to an object's creation rather than its initialization.

Comment: @chepner i know but `__init__` gets called no matter what (unless you break the rules with metaclass,eh). So why not.. (but i get your point)

Comment: So does `__new__`. (Actually, `__new__` is *more* likely to be called, since its return value determines whether `__init__` is, in fact, called.)

Comment: @chepner: `__new__` vs `__init__` is not the primary problem. It's that overriding `__del_` is **not** a reliable way to determine if a class instance has been destroyed or not (including because it was created as a local variable in a function that has returned). `__del__()` is not like a C++ destructor — see its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__). AFAIK, there's no way to track the existence of a class instance in Python except by some other means.

Comment: The problem with `__del__` not being called is when the object is being destroyed because the interpreter itself is shutting down. The list itself may or may not even exist by the time `__del__` might be called in that situation, so I don't think it's a concern.

Comment: @chepner: I think you are mistaken about `__del__` not being called only being an issue when the interpreter shuts down.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the `all` statement?

(Untested)

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x: int) -> None:
        self.x = x

def main():
    a1 = A(128)
    a2 = A(128)
    a3 = A(128)
    l = [a1, a2, a3]
    if all([i.x == 128 for i in l]):
        print("All instances have same x")
    else:
        print("Some instances have different x")

main()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't say that the x value is stable and not being changed in function of time, so the first part of your code is incorrect

Comment: @Developeeer My solution allows you to custom the attribute and it’s not built in :)

Comment: @Jonathan1609, I'm still checking your solution and understanding it

Comment: @Developeeer: On the plus side, this answer sidesteps the issue of whether the instances of `A` currently exist or not.

Comment: @Jonathan1609: I meant it as just an example to illustrate the issue. The `A` instance might get deleted *at some point* or simply be a local variable in a function that discarded when the function returns — all before the instance attribute check gets made. If you don't know for sure what instances exist, you can't do what's desired reliably.

Comment: @martineau ok i updated the code to support function discardings and deletions

Comment: @Jonathan1609: Python isn't like C++. If you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) closely, there's no guarantees made about *when*, if ever, `__del__()` will get called—unless, of course, you explicitly call the dunder method). There are a number of questions related to precisely this mistaken assumption here on stackoverflow.